# how can i achieve this mysql group query

Tags: mysql, group-by

I have two tables A and B.
My goal is to list every row from A, while attach the SUM of 'amount' from B.

like this:

```
SELECT a.name, 
       SUM(b.amount) as amount 
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b ON a.id = b.a_id 
GROUP BY a.id
```

No probleam until this, but i also need to check whether the B table's 'shop_id' matches a value, and if does, i want that single row's 'amount', and not the SUM of all groupped rows. I hope it is understandable.

```
Table A  
id     name
----------------
1      john
2      doe
3      smith

Table B
a_id    amount    shop
-----------------------
1         4        1
1         3        2
2         2        2
2         7        3
3         3        3
3         1        2
```

Desired result with 'shop'=1:

```
name   amount    shop
---------------------
john     4         1         //no SUM, only the value of amount where shop=1
doe      9         0         //sum(7,2) because shop is not 1
smith    4         0         //sum(3,1)
```

I was thinking of an if statement at the SUM() selection something similar to this, but the below statement returns not the desired groupped row value

```
SELECT a.name,
       ( CASE
           WHEN b.shop <> 1 THEN Sum(b.amount)
           ELSE b.amount
         end ) AS amount,
       ( CASE
           WHEN b.shop <> 1 THEN 0
           ELSE b.shop
         end ) AS shop
FROM   a
       LEFT JOIN b
              ON a.id = b.a_id
GROUP  BY a.id
```

Any ideas ? Is there a way to put this condition to the GROUP like: `case shop<>1 THEN .... ELSE GROUP BY a.id` ??

Answer (score 2):

You were on the right track to use what is called conditional aggregation.  Here is a version which should work:

```
SELECT
    a.name,
    CASE WHEN MAX(CASE WHEN b.shop = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) > 0
         THEN SUM(CASE WHEN b.shop = 1 THEN b.amount ELSE 0 END)
         ELSE SUM(b.amount) END AS amount,
    MAX(CASE WHEN b.shop = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS shop
FROM a
LEFT JOIN b
    ON a.id = b.a_id
GROUP BY
    a.name;
```

[image]

### Demo

Comment: Im testing it, so far looks nice. Thank you for the fast response. Do you think Madhur's solution would run slower ?

Comment: Good question, and you can test both queries.  His answer looks cleaner and more sophisticated than mine.

Comment: You can replace SUM() with Max() when shop = 1; otherwise if OP has duplicate data for shop = 1; then it will calculate sum, instead of just one of the values; +1

Answer (score 2):

- You will need to `Left Join` twice with the table `b`.
- First Join will enable computation of Sum.
- Second Join will join only when shop = 1. So if we get some non-null value due to second join, we will consider that, else the Sum

Try the following:

```
SELECT 
  a.id, 
  a.name, 
  COALESCE(MAX(b2.amount), SUM(b1.amount)) AS amount, 
  COALESCE(b2.shop, 0) AS shop 
FROM a 
LEFT JOIN b AS b1 ON a.id = b1.a_id 
LEFT JOIN b AS b2 ON a.id = b2.a_id AND b2.shop = 1
GROUP BY a.id, a.name
```

**Result**

```
| id  | name  | amount | shop |
| --- | ----- | ------ | ---- |
| 1   | john  | 4      | 1    |
| 2   | doe   | 9      | 0    |
| 3   | smith | 4      | 0    |
```

---

[View on DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ZrRGZy361xpHUZM28nHYk/0)

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen thanks; I doubt about its efficiency though, due to double join.

Comment: @Ninet9 did you benchmark the two queries ? What is the result ?

Comment: No, i dont have the db filled up yet. But the efficiency is pretty important, table A will have around 10,000, B about 50,000 rows with both having lot more fields. For the first look, Tim's solution seems faster, but i will test both.

Comment: @Ninet9 Please see: [How to accept an answer for closure](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/5235). Thanks :)